# How to rank pages that require user input?

Tags: seo, google, links, backlinks

We have an automobile product page where we describe details about the specific car / bike like it's images, videos, news, reviews etc.

Now, we are planning to show the price and EMI of these automobiles as well. The prices & EMIs varies from city to city. We are planning to create EMI and price related page for every model-city combination.

The only problem is how do we create links for these EMI and price pages? Currently, the plan is to show upfront Price and EMI of some popular city and give a link to the user to select their city. Once the user selects the city, he/she will be taken to the city-based EMI / Price page. But the problem is crawler will not be able to crawl these pages and users first need to select the city. How do we solve this and make these links crawlable & rank them on google search?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the acronym EMI.  Doing some research indicates that it may mean "Equated Monthly Installment" ie, the monthly payment for a car loan.  Is that correct in this context?

Answer (score 1):

**Goal:** Rank pages after user input to display Automobile - EMI - specific information.

**Assumption 1:** The pages that display Automobile - EMI - specific information are temporary and dynamic links.

**Assumption 2:** The pages that display Automobile - EMI - specific information are permanent static links that users are redirected once user inputs data.

**Solution:**

Given that you're following Assumption-1, I suggest you move to Assumption-2 if your goal is to rank data-specific pages.

For this to work you can do the following:

1. Backlink data-specific pages on the global page as well as the proper navigation menu with the hierarchy to follow.
2. Have the list of data-specific pages on the sitemap.
3. Have the data-specific pages SEO compliant with the target keywords not overlapping other pages.

**Suggestion:**

The global page, where you get users to input data, make it focus on a generic keyword followed by data-specific pages to target on the generic keyword, geo-keyword, and relevant keywords.

This will help you follow a proper structure for the crawler to understand keeping in mind that the links for data-specific inputs are permanent pages that actually exist on the website rather than a dynamic link created on user-data input.

Answer (score -1):

By listing the pages in a Sitemap:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156184?hl=en

Comment: But there's a problem here - https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/123093/74731  It doesn't guarantee indexing and chances of getting good rank is minimal

Comment: But you asked how to make the pages crawlable. Whether or not they get indexed and how well they rank is far too broad a topic to answer here.